# ggplot2: how to create correct legend after using scale_xx_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with three different lines. I want one of those lines to have points on as well. I also want the two lines without points to be thicker than the one without points. I have managed to get the plot I want, but I the legend isn't keeping up.

```
library(ggplot2)

y <- c(1:10, 2:11, 3:12)
x <- c(1:10, 1:10, 1:10)
testnames <- c(rep('mod1', 10), rep('mod2', 10), rep('meas', 10))
df <- data.frame(testnames, y, x)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=testnames)) +
   geom_line(aes(size=testnames)) +
   scale_size_manual("", values=c(0.5,1,1)) +
   geom_point(aes(alpha=testnames), size=5, shape=4) +
   scale_alpha_manual("", values=c(1, 0, 0))
```

[image]

I can remove the second (black) legend:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=testnames)) +
   geom_line(aes(size=testnames)) +
   scale_size_manual("", values=c(0.5,1,1), guide='none') +
   geom_point(aes(alpha=testnames), size=5, shape=4) +
   scale_alpha_manual("", values=c(1, 0.05, 0.05), guide='none')
```

[image]

But what I really want is a merge of the two legends - a legend with colours, cross only on the first variable (`meas`) and the lines of `mod1` and `mod2` thicker than the first line. I have tried guide and override, but with little luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need transparency to hide the shapes for `mod1` and `mod2`. You can omit these points from the plot and legend by setting their shape to `NA` in `scale_shape_manual`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = testnames, size = testnames)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = testnames), size = 5) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(0.5, 2, 2)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(8, NA, NA))
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

---

**NOTE**: I used some more distinct values in the size-scale and another shape in order to better illustrate the effect.